# Run Logon Script before desktop loads

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-authentication, windows-scripting, winlogon

So basically what im trying to do:

I want to run a logon script after a user logs in (my current script is a powershell script but i wouldnt mind any other type). This script should halt the login process and ask for a userinput, only if the user provides valid input the logon process should finish, otherwise the user should automatically get logged out.

Can i achieve this using a Powershell script?
I have my test script rolled out via GPO, i can´t figure out how to halt the logon process and furthermore the Dialog Box starts minimized.

Would appreciate if you guys have any ideas if this is possible! :)

Comment: You should look into using an alternative shell, which is launched instead of Explorer.  This could interact with the user and logoff or start Explorer, depending on the input.  Check out this thread to get you started:  [How to run an application as shell replacement on Windows 10 Enterprise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/shell-launcher)

Comment: Why does it matter whether the desktop loads first or not?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart i basically want do multifactor autentication and therefore  prompt the user for a Token and verify it. In my environment i have a third party application that does handle the windows logon, which i cannot modify an therefore i have to do it after the actual logon but before the user can do anything

Comment: @boxdog Looks like an interesting approach, thanks for the comment, i will look into that!

Comment: I think this question is better suited for serverfault than stackoverflow.

Comment: Try to look at `SampleWrapExistingCredentialProvider` from Credential Provider Samples. There you can add extra fields and control the `GetSerialization` method of wrapped provider.